# Vizing's Theorem Proof: Let a C be a optimal ($\Delta$ + 1)-edge colouring of G, if C isn't possible then $\chi' \leq \Delta$ + 1?

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory

I am trying yo understand Vizing's proof as found in the book Graph Theory With Applications by authors Bondy and Murty.

The proof starts this way:

Proof:  Let G be a simple graph. By virtue of (6.1) we need only show
that $\chi' \leq \Delta$  + 1. Suppose, then, that $ \chi' > \Delta + 1$. Let C = ($E_1 , E_2 , .... , E_{\Delta+1}$) be
an optimal ($\Delta$ + 1)-edge colouring of G and let *u* be a vertex such that
c(*u*) < d(*u*). In which c(*u*) is the number of distinct colors of incident  edges in *u*. d(*u*) is the degree of *u*.

Then the authors went on to show that such coloring it's not possible. I understood how they concluded that such C isn't possible. What I would like to know is why C not being possible implicates that  $\chi' \leq \Delta$  + 1.

Thanks!

Comment: If it's not the case that $\chi'>\Delta+1$ then it must be the case that $\chi'\leq\Delta+1$.  I don't think that's what you are asking, but that's how the question seems to read.  Can you clarify it?  Also, what are $c(u)$ and $d(u)$?

Comment: @saulspatz ,  c(u) is the number of distinct colors of incident edges in u. d(u) is the degree of u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go back to the definition of "improvement" of an edge coloring.  They say that one $k$-edge coloring is an improvement on another if the sum of the number of colors at each vertex is greater.  Then they say that a $k$-edge coloring is optimal if it cannot be improved on.

If the edge-chromatic number is greater than $\Delta+1$ then there must be an optimal $\Delta+1$-edge coloring that is not a proper edge coloring.  Otherwise, we could keep improving any $\Delta+1$-edge coloring until the sum of the colors represented at the vertices is equal to the sum of the vertex degrees, at which point we have a proper $\Delta+1$-edge coloring.

The proof shows that an optimal $\Delta+1$-edge coloring that is not a proper edge coloring cannot exist, so $$\chi'\leq\Delta+1$$.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot, make perfect sense.

Comment: It was my pleasure.